# MySQL Workbench 6.1 - No option to insert rows?

Tags: mysql, ubuntu, mysql-workbench

Version 5.2 of MySQL Workbench has an option to add rows to a table graphically, right clicking the table name from the list of tables. This option is really lacking in MySQL Workbench 6.1 or is it hidden?

On an Ubuntu 13.10.

### MySQL Workbench 6.1

[image: no 'null' row to insert]
[image: no 'Edit Table Data' option]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The version in the the Ubuntu 14.04 repositories seems to be working and is the new version of the program.

Answer (score 4):

I'm usually looking at the contents of a table before I add a row to it, and there's always an empty row at the bottom of the result set (the whole row is nullified) which you can click on and add content to. Then just hit "Apply".

Comment: Your table is ReadOnly so you do not have the option.

Comment: It is saying that it is readonly because "The table has no unique row identifier (primary key or a  NOT NULL unique index)"; but the table has, see images from my own answer; I think it should be a bug.

Comment: @Kassius can you take a look at the "Indexes" tab and see if there is a key called "PRIMARY" in the list? It should be associated with the "id" column in your table.

Comment: It has; I was able to add rows, but then the program sets the table as readonly and can add again after closing the server tab and reconnecting; then add a row, and it set as readonly again.

Answer (score 2):

It should be a bug. It says that the Table is read only, because it don't have a primary key, but the table has it.

Table has readonly flag and it's tooltip says that "The table has no unique row identifier (primary key or a NOT NULL unique index)"
[image: readonly flag]

---

But table has primary key:
[image]

---

This is version 5.2.47... i uninstalled the new, because I think it is a bug.
[image]

Comment: Can you screenshot the "Indexes" tab?

Comment: I took a screenshot, but from the 5.2.47 version.

Comment: I aslo have the exact same thing, did you find a solution or are you still using the older version?

Comment: Are you using the version you downloaded at the site or Ubuntu repositories? The version at the Ubuntu 14.04 repositories seems to be working and is the new version.