# MySQL read only the table has no unique row identifier (primary key or a NOT NULL unique index)

Tags: mysql, readonly

MySQL 5.7

I know squat about databases but I do have a custom program that uses the databases I have. If I want to use another account (twitter) with my program, I need to make all the datasets. I've done this a few times before. It always takes me a while to figure out, but I get there.

Yet this time I'm stuck with a read-only dataset.

What I usually do is I make a new schema with a proper name.
I then go to one of my other schemas, export what I need ('sources' and 'entries') and import them to my newly made schema.

That should work and it looked like it worked again this time. BUT there is a difference... It's read-only and I am way to green to tackle this on my own. I'll try to investigate a bit more myself, but some help sure would be appreciated : ) The warning is: "read only: the table has no unique row identifier (primary key or a NOT NULL unique index)": I couldn't find any results with this exact warning so I thought to post it here :)

Thank you!

Devvie

Comment: I think you perhaps need to add an unique index to your table.

Comment: Thank you, I tried looking at that but I'm quickly pointed to manuals and instructions I don't even know where to enter or do, let alone that I'd understand them. Is it a simple thing to do?
https://www.google.com/search?biw=1183&bih=650&tbs=qdr%3Ay&ei=lbttWuGyNoXMwQLAiK24Dg&q=how+to+add+unique+index+in+mysql+to+solve+read-only+problem&oq=how+to+add+unique+index+in+mysql+to+solve+read-only+problem&gs_l=psy-ab.3..33i160k1.31124.37563.0.37741.39.37.0.0.0.0.152.3088.27j10.37.0.crnk_dmh...0...1.1.64.psy-ab..2.34.2897...0i22i30k1j33i22i29i30k1j33i21k1.0.d0_9VsgGV00

Comment: You have to, at least, show us the SQL for the creation of table in question. Then we can add the unique index for you.

Comment: I was looking around myself - is this what you mean? https://snag.gy/wsxolj.jpg (studying this thread too: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22991452/mysql-workbench-6-1-no-option-to-insert-rows)

Comment: Thought: should I update the checkboxes here to match one of the other accounts, like this? https://snag.gy/tzwGyf.jpg

Comment: yeay! solved. If you are stuck to with a read-only schema after exporting and importing your data (csv), you still might need to 'check the boxex'. How? In my case, I went to 'schema' and 'sources', clicked the little wrench tool and got a table (see screenshot above) with all kinds of check boxes. No idea what they were, but after matching them to what my other accounts & schemas were using, all was working. No idea what this has to do with Unique Identifier and or Unique Index... For me, I consider this question solved and I'm so grateful I never had to officially do work on databases ;p ♥

Answer (score 0):

See my comments above on how to solve it.

TL;DL - if you are stuck with a read only schema after importing your data, you might want to tick the correct checkboxes for your schemas. Select schema, select Wrench Icon and match the table to be the same as the schema's table you imported from.

Thank you all.